# importing a CSV file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io, csv, import, textscan

How can I import a CSV file into MATLAB?. A row in the file i am working with looks like:

```
SUNW,2-Jan-98,1998,5,40.125,41.5
```

There are 36 columns and 10107 rows. The first row contains the column headers. It seems that MATLAB doesn't support importing such kind of CSV files. Using the following `textscan`function reads the whole data into one cell array.

```
data = textscan(fid, '%s %s %d %d %f %f', ...
    'HeaderLines',1, 'Delimiter',',', 'CollectOutput',1);
```

Is there a way I could read the data into different variable for each column?

Answer (score 2):

Example 6 in the [`textscan` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) seems to cover the use case that you're interested in:

> Using a text editor, create a comma-delimited file data2.csv that
>   contains the lines
>
> ```
>     abc, 2, NA, 3, 4
>     // Comment Here
>     def, na, 5, 6, 7
> ```
>
> Designate the input that textscan should treat as comments or empty
>   values:
>
> ```
>     fid = fopen('data2.csv');
>     C = textscan(fid, '%s %n %n %n %n', 'delimiter', ',', ...
>                  'treatAsEmpty', {'NA', 'na'}, ...
>                  'commentStyle', '//');
>     fclose(fid);
> ```
>
> textscan returns a 1-by-5 cell array C with the following cells:
>
> ```
>     C{1} = {'abc'; 'def'}
>     C{2} = [2; NaN]
>     C{3} = [NaN; 5]
>     C{4} = [3; 6]
>     C{5} = [4; 7]
> ```

While it doesn't explicitly assign each column to a separate variable, you can easily do something like `col1 = C{1};`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have MATLAB 2011b then you can use the [spreadsheet import tool](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/import_export/f5-100860.html).